# How to make a reference to a uid stored in Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a constant referencing the current user's uid , but it accesses the red one not the blue one as it should (see image)

[image]

Here is what I havve written so far:

```
  let user = Auth.auth().currentUser!
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            let document = db.collection("users").document(user.uid);
            document.getDocument(completion: {(snapshot, err) in
                if let name = snapshot?.data()?["first name"] as? String
                {
                    self.userNameLabel.text = name
                }
                else
                {   print(user.uid)
                    self.userNameLabel.text = "Didn't work"
                }
            })

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: user.uid)
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print(document.data()["first_name"])
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it automatic, like when a new user signs up,I want to be able to access its name right away.

Comment: Please check the updated answer.